# fatal error: call to a member function delete() on a non-object wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to delete rows from db and getting this error. I googled and tried all the possible solution still no luck. I also mentioned "global $wpdb" but dont know why getting this error.

```
<?php
if($_POST['array'])
{
    global $wpdb;
    $productArray = $_POST["array"];
    $count = count($productArray);
    $table_name = "wp_cause_woocommerce_product";

    for( $i=0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
        $wpdb->delete( $table_name, array( 'product_ID' => $productArray[$i] ), array( '%d' ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have all those array values in your table?

Comment: For debugging purposes I would print_r($wpdb) just to see if it's filled with the object you actually want. Your code seems fine.

Comment: print_r($wpdb) i did this .. nothing has shown =>Jordy . yes I have all values =>Feroz

Comment: is this file inside your theme or somewhere else?

Comment: the file path :

E:\xampp\htdocs\fundraise\wp-content\themes\aidreform\include\cs_product_delete.php

Comment: @WahidSherief from which page you are calling this page. What is the url to that file

Comment: E:\xampp\htdocs\fundraise\wp-content\themes\aidreform\include\cs_cause.php

@Sabari

Comment: @WahidSherief are you able to call any other WordPress function. Can you try calling the function get_header() and tell me what is the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72123/discussion-between-wahidsherief-and-sabari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are not getting the WordPress functions.

Add this in to the top of your code.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/fundraise/wp-load.php' );
```

If you change your project path make sure you update the path to wp-load.php.

If you will change your project path in future, you can try this

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 
require_once( dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))) . '/wp-load.php');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just add the below lines on top of the page and its working. I had to relate the file with wp functionality thats it :

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/fundraise/wp-load.php' );
```